# Custom SELECT Query With Multiple Meta Values (Ordering Problem)

Tags: customization, query, mysql

I have two custom meta values that I am using for an events list and have almost got everything working perfectly except for the ordering. I have two dates (event_date and event_enddate). One of these is a start date which is always present, and the other is an end date which is only used when needed. I have created a query which lists all dates where either of these fields are equal or greater to today's date, which works fine. However, I want all of the events to be ordered solely by the event_date field. How can I do this? I've spent all day trying to do this and just can't work it out!

Here's my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT wposts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE ((wpostmeta.meta_key = 'event_enddate' AND wpostmeta.meta_value >= CURDATE())
 OR (wpostmeta.meta_key = 'event_date' AND wpostmeta.meta_value >= CURDATE()))
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN(15)
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can achieve this with [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and avoid the custom SQL:

```
$today = date( 'Y-m-d' );
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'ID',
            'terms' => 15
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'event_enddate',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'meta_value' => $today,
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
$events = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Hey Milo, I tried your code and it didn't work at first (the posts that were being shown were featuring all kinds of dates), so I've been tinkering with it a bit and have now got it so that it's showing exactly the posts I want, but as soon as I add any info on the ordering it goes wrong! Here's the code which brings my unordered data perfectly:

Comment: `$today = date( 'Y/m/d' );
 $args = array(
       'tax_query' => array(
          array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
  'field' => 'ID',
  'terms' => 15
  )
 ),
 'meta_query' => array(
 'relation' => 'OR',
 array(
  'key' => 'event_enddate',
  'value' => $today,
  'compare' => '>='
 ),
        array(
  'key' => 'event_date',
  'value' => $today,
  'compare' => '>='
)       
)
);`
I've tried adding this to the bottom to get the ordering but then I just get the wrong values. Why is this? What else can I try?
`'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'`

Comment: @RussellSlater After you query for events, add `print_r($events);` to your template and you'll see the SQL query that WordPress generated. That may give you some clue as to what's going wrong. I thought what I had was working, I tried it out with a bit of test data- maybe a date format issue?

Comment: Okay, cheers Milo. That has shed some light. Specifically, there's definitely an error in the sorting:
`Array ( [key] => event_enddate [value] => 2012/05/08 [compare] => >= ) ) [meta_value] => 2012/05/08 [meta_compare] => >= [orderby] => meta_value [order] => ASC [error]`
I'll see if I can work out what's causing it, but it may well be the date format I guess.